# Finding the proportion of values that are less than a specific value in a Series

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, scipy, statistics

I have a data from a website given [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Alo47BBiqLE0dERoTWtkczVrcGNWOE5tUmJXYUp4R3c&usp=sharing)

I have the first column as`DataFrame` for computations.

```
df.head()

> 21.36
  11.33
  8.19
  18.36
```

I computed the mean and standard deviation using

```
m = df.mean()
st = df.std(ddof =0)
```

If I want to calculate the `Z` Score of any value, say 17.83 I can simply do it by using

```
z_score =  (17.83 -m)/st
```

**How can I find out that what proportion of values are less and/or greater than this specific value?**

(using Pandas and if not possible, Scipy)

Comment: Everything greater than or less than would simply be not equal to. `df['your column'].ne(z_score).sum() / len(df)`

Comment: I know. that's why I asked this specifically cos doing it manually by selecting negative z values or subtracting result from 1 is tedious (z table).